# New Task resulting in java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread even with Platform.runLater() wrap

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have tried wrapping the ObservableList in the Platform.runLater(), but it gives me an error:

> local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or
>   effectively final

I can't think of anything to fix this error. Here's my code:

```
    Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override public Void call() {                
                try {

                    for (int i = 0; i < obLstDataset.size(); i++){
                        // **************************                        
                        //doing other stuff here
                        // ************************** 
                        if (pageVLEDEResult.contains("something")) {                            
                            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                    obLstInvalid.add((String)obLstDataset.get(i));    
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        else if (pageVLEDEResult.contains("something else")){
                            if (i!=0){
                                i--;
                            }
                        }

                        updateProgress (i+1, obLstDataset.size());

                    }

                } catch (IOException | FailingHttpStatusCodeException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(VehicleLicenceExpiryDateEnquirer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
```

Comment: What is preventing you from declaring the field final?

Comment: I thought it wanted obLstInvalid or obLstDataset to be final (which they already were). In reality it was varialbe "i" that needed to be final, totally missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to make the variables accessed in the runLater final.  Also, it is very bad practice to modify the for-loop variable (in this case i) in the for loop.  So I have re-written it into a while loop.

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override public Void call() {                
            try {
                int i=0;
                do {
                    // **************************                        
                    //doing other stuff here
                    // ************************** 
                    if (pageVLEDEResult.contains("something")) {                           
                        final List <not sure what class this is> fobLstInvalid = obLstInvalid;
                        final List <not sure what class this is> fobLstDataset = obLstDataset;
                        final int fi = i;

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                obLstInvalid.add((String)obLstDataset.get(fi));    
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    else if (pageVLEDEResult.contains("something else")){
                        if (i!=0){
                            i--;
                        }
                    }

                    updateProgress (i+1, obLstDataset.size());
                    i++;
                } while (i < obLstDataset.size())

            } catch (IOException | FailingHttpStatusCodeException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(VehicleLicenceExpiryDateEnquirer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you :)

Can you please explain why it is considered bad practice to alter variable i?

Wow, I figured out, specifically the i variable, needs to be final. My ObersableList vars were already final, that's why I was so confused - I didn't think about i!!

Thanks for the fix.

Comment: The comment about the i variable in the for loop is not about final.  It is about the meaning of a for loop.  The definition of a for loop is that the loop variable is controlled in the loop condition at the top of a for loop.

Comment: If I could format my comments correctly you would see there was a paragraph space between my question about the bad practice and the realization that var i needed to be final to remove the error I was getting. Thanks for the for-loop tip, I guess for readability it makes things easier, but from a technical point I don't get why changing for-loop var would be such a bad idea - I'll keep it in mind though :)